# List out texts between brackets

Tags: sql

I have a text  `'This is the text {{Test1}}{{Test2}}.'`. I want to list out texts between `{{}}`

example:

```
Test1
Test2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In (two) separate rows? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Well I want a brand new Ferrari. Think we can make a deal? Seriously, read [ask] and edit your question to include the tags for the relevant database and version, and your current best attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(substring_index(substring_index(myColumn,'{{',-2),'{{',1), '}}', '') foo1,
  REPLACE(substring_index(substring_index(myColumn,'{{',-1),'{{',1), '}}', '') foo2
FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.myColumn LIKE '%{{%';
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.